# TCSH: How to have environment variables in completion?

Tags: unix, tcsh, completion

I am creating completions for `TCSH`. Is it possible to use environment variables in completion?

I added something like below where `$ROOT` is the environment variable

```
    complete go \
      "p@1@D:$ROOT/@"
```

But when I try to `ssh` into the box 
it gives an error saying `$ROOT` is not known. `$ROOT` would be set later by sourcing a file once i ssh and would change depending on the directory I am in.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `$ROOT` variable. The `complete` try to evaluate the expression and the `$ROOT` doesn't exist.

I think you misunderstand this `complete`. The evaluation is "build-time" (at execute of `complete`) not "run-time" (when you try complete with `TAB` the command `go`).